# D3 empty placeholders in scaleBand?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a bar chart where the x axis is a range of dates. We have four views:

- YEAR - shows 12 months of data
- MONTH - shows (28/9, 30, or 31) days
  in selected month
- DAY - shows 24 hours
- HOUR - shows 60 minutes

I first began plotting the x-axis with scaleTime, but found the spaces between the bars was inconsistent and then converted the plotting to use scaleBand. After spending a day with that, I've gotten everything completely uniform, but now I've run into the problem that it only displays bars for dates if values are provided for that interval, and it does not display empty values for intervals that do not contain data.

For clarity, what I would like to happen is to show a bar chart with places for 12 months, or whatever the interval is, even though only July and August contain data. Right now if I put only July and August data in, it returns a chart with two bars.

Is it possible to add the spaces to the x axis even if there is no data to represent for that period? Is this what is meant by implicit? If so, it looks like scaleBand won't do that. Can anyone recommend an alternative scale function that will accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

A little code:

```
self.x = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(self.pointsArray.map(function(d) {
        return new Date(d.start)
     }))
     .rangeRound([0, self.width], .05)
     .padding(.1)
self.g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + self.height + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(self.x)
        .ticks(sections)
        .tickSizeOuter(0)
        .tickPadding(6)
```

Comment: You should really be using scaleTime. Seems like you gave up too quickly. "Is it possible to add the spaces to the x axis even if there is no data to represent for that period?" Thats exactly what linear scales, such as scaleTime, can do for you.

Comment: What methods do you use to make them evenly spaced? What I read online is that the variance between month size causes uneven gaps between the bars, which is what was happening to me. The scaleBand function was a perfect solution for that.

Comment: @Kraken You are correct in using a band scale here instead of a time scale: your dates are categorical variables in this case. The solution is very simple: pass the domain manually instead of mapping the data array.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Does that mean I have to manually build the data objects for empty values and insert them into my data array?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried .domain([self.pointsArray[0], self.pointsArray[self.pointsArray.length - 1]]), but now the bars are laying on top of each other. I can add more code if you let me know what you need to see.

Comment: Thanks! That was enough info to figure it out. I created the domain using the interval function.

Comment: @Kraken good. I wrote an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the empry spaces you want because of this:

```
.domain(self.pointsArray.map(function(d) {
    return new Date(d.start)
 }))
```

As you can see, your domain contain only the categorical variables present in the data.

The simple solution is passing an array manually (or writing a function to get the interval array you want) to the domain. For instance, the months:

```
.domain(["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Out","Nov","Dec"])
```

Here is a demo, the data array has information for only four months (Apr, May, Jun and Nov), but all the months show up in the axis:

```js
var data = [{
  month: "Apr",
  value: 10
}, {
  month: "May",
  value: 30
}, {
  month: "Jun",
  value: 40
}, {
  month: "Nov",
  value: 10
}];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value
  })])
  .range([120, 10]);
var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Out", "Nov", "Dec"])
  .range([40, 280])
  .padding(0.2);

var rects = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d.month)
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d.value)
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return 120 - yScale(d.value)
  });

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,0)").call(yAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,120)").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```